# Unable to read data from CBOR File

Tags: java, json, data-binding, jackson

My Aim is to store the instances of TargetModel class into CBOR Format using files. If there is any other approach, it works for me!

I am using [Jackson CBOR API](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-cbor) to write to and read the data from and write the data to a file.

I am using [writeValue](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#writeValue%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.Object%29) method of ObjectMapper Class to write an instance of the [TargetModel](https://github.com/ViDA-NYU/ache/blob/master/src/main/java/focusedCrawler/target/TargetModel.java) but when I try to read the data it throws a [JsonMappingException](http://jackson.codehaus.org/0.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException.html) when I try to read the object using [ReadValue](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.Class%29) .

Please help me! I am in serious trouble because of this.

Mainclass.java

```
package cborStoring;

public class MainClass {

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{

    String targetfilePath = "/home/vaio/Documents/mySampleFile";

    CBORWriter myCborWriter = new CBORWriter();

    TargetModel sampleModel = new TargetModel("rajat", "dfdsf");
//  TestClass sampleModel = new TestClass();

    Object inputObject = (Object)sampleModel;


    myCborWriter.writeObject(inputObject, targetfilePath);

    CBORReader myCborReader = new CBORReader();
    Object readObj = myCborReader.readObject(targetfilePath);

    TargetModel myModel = (TargetModel)readObj;
//  TestClass myModel = (TestClass)readObj;

    System.out.println("Program Ends!");

}
}
```

CBORWriter.java

```
package cborStoring;

public class CBORWriter {

public CBORWriter(){

}

public void writeObject(Object inputObject, String targetfilePath) throws Exception{

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetfilePath, true);

    if (!(new File(targetfilePath)).exists())
        (new File(targetfilePath)).createNewFile();

    CBORFactory f = new CBORFactory();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(f);

    mapper.writeValue(fos,inputObject);


    fos.close();
}

}
```

CBORReader.java

```
package cborStoring;

public class CBORReader {

public CBORReader(){

}

public Object readObject(String targetFilePath) throws Exception{

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(targetFilePath);

    CBORFactory f = new CBORFactory();

    ObjectMapper myMapper = new ObjectMapper(f);

    CBORParser myCborParser = f.createParser(fis);

    //Object readObject = myMapper.readValue(myCborParser, Object.class);
    //Object readObject = myMapper.readValue(myCborParser, TargetModel.class); : This does NOT Work throws JSONMappingException

    Object readObject = myMapper.readValue(myCborParser, TargetModel.class);

    return readObject;

}

}
```

Comment: Please include actual text of exception; type itself won't help a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what the underlying problem is, but code can be simplified quite a bit, like so:

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new CBORFactory());
   mapper.writeValue(file, objectToWrite);
   TargetModel result = mapper.readValue(file, TargetModel.class);

and there is usually not much point in separately constructing parsers or generators.
Also, make sure to use the latest available version; 2.5.3 at this point.